# Finding even permutations using Haskell

Tags: haskell, permutation

I tried to figure out how to find the even permutations out of the set {permutations [1..n]}. I have asked this question before on a different forum, and got an answer that worked namely the code was:

```
Import Data.List

-- number of inversions in a permutation
inversions as = sum $ map go (tails as)
where go [] = 0
go (x:xs) = length $ filter (<x) xs

evenPerm as = even (inversions as)

alternating n = [ p | p <- permutations [1..n], evenPerm p ]
```

I understand the last line in the code: `alternating n =[p | p <- permutations [1..n], evenPerm p]`. That is, the `p` of the set `{permutations [1..n]}` such that they are even permutations. The function `evenPerm` as I think I understand too. It is just the even elements of the set `{inversion as}`. The thing I truly don't understand how it is working is the inversion as function. Naively, how I would imagine things to work is take the element of the set {permutations [1..n]} [1..n] i.e. (1,2,3,..,n) and compare every other element in the set to this one and count how many moves you have to make to get it in that form, but how you go about doing that in Haskell?

Comment: `evenPerm` is not the elements of any 'set' (if we are taking sets to be represented by lists). `even :: Int -> Bool` (loosely speaking) so `evenPerm` is a predicate on sets. `inversions` is a somewhat curious function which computes the number of elements in a set *of sets* smaller than the first 'set', using the lexographic ordering on lists. Really, this has little to do with Haskell - it is more (somewhat non-elementary) set theory than anything. All that aside, have you run your functions on a few sample inputs to see what they do in those cases? That usually helps gain an intuition.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the code which was provided to me by someone else. The code works and does exactly what I want it to do, but like I said it was provided to me by someone else, and I am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: How many moves you need to bring `[a1,..,an]` into `[1..n]`? Well, you first need as many moves as needed to sort `[a2,..,an]`, then you need to swap `a1` to its sorted position, i.e. swap it with the longest prefix of `[a2,..,an]` made by elements `<a1`. In your code, `length $ filter (<x) xs` counts this last figure, the `sum` does the recursive step. (Here I ignore the fact that in the recursive step we no longer have all the `1..n` elements, but it can be phrased exactly with a bit more care)

Answer (score 2):

To take a bird’s-eye view, what we want to do is count how many swaps we would need to sort the list in place.  (Equivalently, in the language of group theory, to decompose the permutation into transpositions.) Which sorting algorithm we use to count swaps doesn’t matter for correctness: an even permutation will generate an even number of swaps and an odd permutation an odd number of swaps regardless of how we sort.

Let’s look first at:

```
go [] = 0
go (x:xs) = length $ filter (<x) xs
```

The indentation in that sample is confusing, but `go` is a nested local function of `inversions`.  It appears inside a `where` clause.  The `go` function counts the number of elements in a list that need to be moved *before* the first element in the list, that is, the elements smaller than the head of the list.  It does this by filtering the tail and taking its length.  An empty list has no head, so there’s another pattern matching it for completeness.  (Otherwise, the compiler would complain that some inputs do not match any pattern.)

```
inversions as = sum $ map go (tails as)
```

The `tails` function is from the `Data.List` library that we imported.  It generates a list of shorter and shorter final segments: `tails [1,2,3] = [[1,2,3] [2,3], [3]]`.  We then map `go` onto each final segment in the list, giving us a list of the inversion count for each final segment.  Finally, we sum the counts.

You will often see things like this written as a composition of functions: `inversions = sum . map go . tails`.  That just applies each function from right to left: `tails`, then `map go` on the result, then `sum` on the result of that.

For example.

```
list == [4,3,2,1]
tails list == [[4,3,2,1], [3,2,1], [2,1], [1]]
map go (tails list) == [3,2,1,0]
sum $ map go (tails list) == 6
```

This counts the number of swaps for a bubble sort.  We could theoretically perform the following swaps to sort the list:

```
[4,3,2,1] -- 0 swaps needed to sort [1]
[4,3,1,2] -- 1 swap to sort final sequence [2,1]
[4,1,3,2] -- Which equals go [2,1]
[4,1,2,3] -- 2 additional swaps to sort [3,2,1]
[1,4,2,3] -- Which equals go [3,2,1]
[1,2,4,3]
[1,2,3,4] -- 3 additional swaps to sort [4,3,2,1]
          -- Which equals go [4,3,2,1]
```

This is far from a minimal number of swaps, but we just need some count for some sorting algorithm, and that one is simple.

The next step is

```
evenPerm as = even (inversions as)
```

This is a predicate that simply tells us whether the result of the computation we just looked at was even or odd.  It could also have been defined as `even . inversions`, or `even . sum . map go . tails`.

```
alternating n = [ p | p <- permutations [1..n], evenPerm p ]
```

This is a list comprehension.  It calls another function from `Data.List`, `permutations`, to generate a list of all permutations.  It then adds a permutation *p* to our output list if and only if `evenPerm p` is true.

This could also have been written as `evenPerms = filter evenPerm . permutations`, which is shorter and works with more types, with `alternating n = evenPerms [1..n]`.  That is, given an input list, generate its permutations and apply a filter to them.  (This version of `alternating` only works on numbers, because it uses `[1..n]`, but the algorithm could work just as well on anything with a less-than operator.)

### Cleaned-up Version

```
import Data.List

{- In the type signatures below, capitalized type names are specific types.
 - Lowercase type parameters are generic.  Ord, to the left of the => sign,
 - is the type class of all types with an ordering relation.  So, the argu-
 - ment is a list of some type a that can be ordered, and the return value
 - is a Bool, True or False.
 -}
isEvenPerm :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
isEvenPerm = even . sum . map go . tails
  where go []     = 0
        go (x:xs) = length . filter (<x) $ xs

evenPerms :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
evenPerms = filter isEvenPerm . permutations

{- This only makes sense for positive whole numbers. -}
alternating :: Integral a => a -> [[a]]
alternating n | n >= 1    = evenPerms [1..n]
              | otherwise = error "Argument must be positive."
```

You can try `evenPerms "abcd"` and `alternating 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP want a "bare hands" code but here is a way with the `combinat` package (I'm a big fan of this package) which can be helpful for future readers. Since it took me a certain time to achieve this I think it's worth to share.

```
import           Data.List hiding (permutations) -- just in case
import           Math.Combinat.Permutations

foo :: [[Double]]
foo =
  [[ permuteList p [phi/2, 1/2, 1/2/phi, 0]  | p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [phi/2, 1/2, -1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [phi/2, -1/2, 1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [-phi/2, -1/2, 1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [-phi/2, -1/2, 1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [-phi/2, -1/2, -1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [-phi/2, 1/2, -1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p] ++
  [ permuteList p [phi/2, 1/2, -1/2/phi, 0]  |  p <- permutations4, isEvenPermutation p]]
  where
    permutations4 = permutations 4
    phi = (1 + sqrt 5) / 2
```